# how split array into another arrary

Tags: perl

```
my  @array = [ 'TEXT[12]|SubText' , 'TEXT2|subText2' , 'TEXT3[34]' ] ;
```

I was looking this array into another array  like

```
('TEXT','12','SubText','TEXT2','SubText2','TEXT3','34')
```

I really dont what do i use with out any extra modules ?

Comment: looks like a strange source data format, it's hard to tell what's going on.. is the pipe a delimiter, and the [] optional?

Comment: its doesnt  matter . if the array look like that how split them into another array !

Comment: how can you say it doesn't matter? data format matters! you can't magically play a movie or view an image file without knowing the data format. your example is stripping out the contents of the square brackets, and anything after a pipe, but it isn't enough of a sample to see all data patterns that may exist (I'd bet).

Comment: `@array = [ ... ]` and `@array = ( ... )` do *very* different things. Are you sure you understand the difference?

Comment: This really seems like someone's homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you splitting the array elements on either `[` or `]` or `|` ? If yes you can do;

```
my @array = ('TEXT[12]|SubText' , 'TEXT2|subText2' , 'TEXT3[34]');
my @result;

foreach(@array) {
        push @result,split/[\[\]\|]+/;
}
```

[Ideone Link](http://www.ideone.com/A3N5p)

Comment: `map` would be even better than using `push` explicitly.

Comment: You only need to quote the `]` so `/[[\]|]+/` is clearer IMO.

Answer (score 3):

That probably doesn't do what you think it does. It creates an anonymous array with the elements 'TEXT[12]|SubText' , 'TEXT2|subText2' , 'TEXT3[34]', and then assigns that as the first element of @array!

But if it *is* what you want to do, then you just have to add the extra step of dereferencing it:

```
my  @array = [ 'TEXT[12]|SubText' , 'TEXT2|subText2' , 'TEXT3[34]' ] ;

for my $item (@array) {
    my @inner_elem_array = map { /(\w+)/g } @$item;
    #Do stuff with the new array here.
}
```

EDIT: In case this still makes no sense to you, I'd recommend reading about [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Comment: quite elegant. I think he's expecting the "do stuff" to append a master array.

Comment: Maybe somethign like this, then?
my @master_array;

push @master_array, [ map { /(\w+)/g } @$item ] for my $item (@array);

Or
my @master_array = map { [ map { /(\w+)/g  } @$_ ] } @array;
But I guess a kitten dies or something when you start piling maps. : )